# Does user defined service register to Servicemanager?

Tags: android

As we know, Android services (Java or native, e.g. Media Player service) should always add themselves to Service Manager (native) using addService() or other ways. Does user defined android.app.Service register to Service Manager in some way? If yes, where is it in source code? If no, how does it do RPC? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How do you mean a user defined service?

Answer (score 0):

To do RPC you suppose to use aidl , [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) is complete example of RPC by aidl.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. My questions is does AIDL mechenism add the service into ServiceManager EVENTUALLY? Can you give some hint? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read about this here: https://github.com/keesj/gomo/wiki/AndroidNativeBinder